# What is the difference between borderlands and borderlands GOTY edition?

Tags: steam, borderlands, version-differences

I want to buy a Borderlands game but what is the difference between the normal and GOTY editions?  I see the normal price for just the game is $20 and the GOTY edition is $30.

Comment: I slightly edited your question to prevent it from being closed as a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, the GOTY edition includes all 4 DLC packs (which were around $10 each originally<sup>[1](http://www.1up.com/news/borderlands-dlc-detailed)</sup>).  It looks like there's currently a couple other bonuses with the Steam version<sup>[2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/901566/)</sup>:

> ### Includes All 4 Borderlands DLC
>
> - Borderlands: The Zombie Island of Dr. Ned
> - Borderlands: Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot
> - Borderlands: The Secret Armory of General Knoxx
> - Borderlands: Claptrap's Robot Revolution
>
> ### Special Offer
>
> - Purchase Borderlands GOTY and get Pandora pdf Map for free.
> - Purchase Borderlands GOTY and join the Duke Nukem Forever: First Access Club

**Edit:** According to M. Travis Volker's comment, the physical version is exactly the same apart from being physical.

Comment: Note: The DLC came as physical media (it's own disk), not codes.  I bought it for Xbox 360 last month from Amazon.

Comment: @M. Travis Volker Thanks, firsthand experience trumps announcements I think.

Comment: Duke Nukem Forever Access? That sounds useful... assuming the game ever comes out :P

Comment: Just make sure you enable the DLC by actually visiting there in single player before attempting to go there in multiplayer - the steam edition, at least, doesn't ask you for the DLC code until the first time you visit there, but that causes a lot of problems when playing online (no one can load until everyone has registered, but you can't actually *SELECT* the registration screen....).  I think only two of the places require registration codes.

Comment: Well and the nice thing about it is that it comes with the DLC disc that you can use over and over again. So like what I did I gave the DLC to all my friends they could play the DLC with me!

Answer (score 1):

The early editions of 360 had slips, the later had a disc.

The PC version had slips.

The ps3 version had slips.

Comment: Good to note. Probably would have been better as a comment.